# Enable Disable Controls in kendo ui grid popup form

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, binding, kendo-ui

I use a grid with popup editor for insert and edit grid rows.
in template I use radio button group

and the properties defined in viewmodel
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            ChequeNaghdiChange:false,
             ChequeReturnedChange:false
........

the NRDisabled  is used for disable and enable control and its work perfectly out of popup by simple set true or false property 
viewModel.set("ChequeNaghdiChange",false);
 kendo.data.binders.NRDisabled = kendo.data.Binder.extend({

```
    refresh: function () {
        if (this.bindings.NRDisabled.get()) {
            this.element.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            this.element.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    }
});
```

It's seems property binding have some problem in kendo.
Best Regards
Amir

Answer (score 0):

I can say that I enable and disable controls in the popup a different way, I attach an event to the grids edit event as follows.

```
.Events(events => events.Edit("onOrderDesignGridEdit"))
```

Then in the edit function I setup the controls that I want enabled or disabled using the model.

```
function onOrderDesignGridEdit(e, a) {
    var model = e.model;
    var overrideTotal = model.OverrideTotal;
    var totalEditor = $("#Total").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
    totalEditor.enable(overrideTotal);            
}
```